# Affinity Publisher: Center symbols vertically around text

Tags: affinity-publisher

I am looking for a way to prepend/append symbols that are vertically aligned with the text. I attached an example - I would like to add crosses to the headings.

I can just put them manually and it works if the heading is a single line

```
+ Introduction +
```

But when it's multi line

```
+ Multi line
heading +
```

I would like both crosses to be centered vertically (and the text itself would be centered horizontally).

Is that possible in the text box tool?

Sample (ignore the bookmark):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can paste a text frame as inline graphics to another piece of text. The pasted frame obeys text positioning settings in the Character panel.

Have a text frame which contains text +  +

Insert the actual text between the + characters:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out!